# Prefixing the results of string.split with the substring indices of each result

Tags: python, string

I have this code, where I am splitting a string every time I find a B:

```
string = "AAABAABAAABIAABIAABAA"
s=[x.strip() for x in string.split('B')]
print '\n'.join(s)
```

The output will be like this:

```
'AAA' 'AA' 'AAA' 'IAA' 'IAA' 'AA'
```

My question is, how can I put a range (first position of char, last position of the char) before the output, like this: `(0,3)AAA (3,5)AA (5,8)AAA (8,11)IAA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple `for` loop with no imports:

```
data = "AAABAABAAABIAABIAABAA"

result, count = [], 0
for s in data.split('B'):
    result.append([(count, count+len(s)), s])
    count += len(s)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[(0, 3), 'AAA'], [(3, 5), 'AA'], 
 [(5, 8), 'AAA'], [(8, 11), 'IAA'], 
 [(11, 14), 'IAA'], [(14, 16), 'AA']]
```

Or if you want it to be separated by `\n`:

```
list_of_strings = map(lambda l: '{}{}'.format(*l), result)
print('\n'.join(list_of_strings))
```

Output:

```
(0, 3)AAA
(3, 5)AA
(5, 8)AAA
(8, 11)IAA
(11, 14)IAA
(14, 16)AA
```

Btw: Don't use `string` as a variable name since it may conflict with the `string` module.

Comment: and if i want to add a '\n' for each element? i dont want to print in line

Comment: `result += [[…]]` is highly unusual in Python. The standard way to  append an element to a list do it is `result.append([])`.

Comment: @EOL: See my edited post. But who said it's the standard way?

Comment: My 7 years of experience with Python say it. :) More seriously, if you look at Python code on this site and elsewhere (blogs, etc.), you will be hard pressed to find the form `result += [[…]]` instead of `result.append([…])`. This is mainly because `append()` is meant to do just this, and because "There should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it.", so virtually everybody uses `append()` to append to a list.

Comment: @EOL: Well, I didn't know about that. Thanks for telling me this so I can improve myself!

Comment: @segfolt: Another reason is that `+=` on lists is more general than `append()`, as it can extend the initial list by another list (this is what `extend()` does). As a consequence, understanding that your original `+= […]` only appends *one* element requires parsing the whole right-hand size contents, whereas this is obvious from `append()`. Therefore `append()` makes the code more legible (faster to understand). When speed matters, `append()` is very likely to be faster too, since it specializes on appending a *single* element.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import re
>>> groups = (((x.start(), x.end()), x.group()) for x in matches)
>>> matches = re.finditer("[^B]+", "AAABAABAAABIAABIAABAA")
>>> groups = (((x.start(), x.end()), x.group()) for x in matches)
>>> ["{}{}".format(*arg) for arg in groups]
['(0, 3)AAA', '(4, 6)AA', '(7, 10)AAA', '(11, 14)IAA', '(15, 18)IAA', '(19, 21)AA']
```

### EDIT:

as segfalt pointed out, I didn't read the question properly...

```
>>> s = 0
>>> res = []
>>> for x in "AAABAABAAABIAABIAABAA".split('B'):
...     res.append("{}{}".format((s, s+len(x)), x))
...     s += len(x)
... 
>>> print "".join(res)
(0, 3)AAA(3, 5)AA(5, 8)AAA(8, 11)IAA(11, 14)IAA(14, 16)AA
```

or

```
>>> print "\n".join(res)
(0, 3)AAA
(3, 5)AA
(5, 8)AAA
(8, 11)IAA
(11, 14)IAA
(14, 16)AA
```

Comment: It seems like the indexes in your list are not those requested by the OP.

Comment: Why use `!r` for the tuple formatting? The standard (`str`) formatting  does just fine, no?

Comment: @EOL, sure. Dunno what I was thinking